# How to Authenticate WebSockets in Tornado

Tags: authentication, websocket, tornado

Is it possible to authenticate WebSocket handshake requests in Tornado? If so, how? If not, where can I check for authenticated user **before** the WebSocket is opened?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question specifically asks about authenticating *before* a websocket connection is opened.

If you're willing to allow the connection to be opened for authentication, then closed if authentication fails (still with the guarantee that no data is sent), then you'll need to define a condition in the `open` method of your socket handler, which checks of the user is authenticated, and refuses to initialize a datastream otherwise ([the WebSocketHandler source](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/tornado/websocket.html#WebSocketHandler) might be of interest here), closing the connection. Open is called on the initial handshake, but no data will be sent until the method returns. You can therefore close the connection before the listening endpoints are initialized.

You can check the request for an authenticated user with [`RequestHandler.current_user`](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.current_user): this is available in any handler, a `WebSocketHandler` included.

You might also be using [authentication cookies](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/security.html) – you can access that cookie inside your socket handler simply by using `self.request.headers`, or with `get_secure_cookie`.

You have something like this, if you choose to use a cookie:

```python
class SocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):

    def open(self):
        user_slug = self.get_secure_cookie("user_cookie")
        if user_slug:
            ...
        else:
            ...
            self.close()
            ...
```

If it's for some reason important that `open` is never called, you might consider calling overriding `get` from `WebSocketHandler`, to preclude all initialization:

```python
class SocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.get_current_user():
            ...
            super(SocketHandler, self).get(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            ...
```

Comment: Yes, the last part is correct and should do the trick. Everything before it is correct but redundant.